# How to convert an flowable list to new flowable list with cummulative sum of previous item

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android

This is very basic but i am very new to RxJava, not able to found a proper solution for the query i have.

Query is like, i am getting a list of flowable (Single stream), and want to transform it to new flowable again (not item by item observable) , as the initial list. While transforming to new flowable list, each item should have cumulative sum of last items.

```
var cumulativeSum: Double = 0.0
var firstObservable: Flowable<List<Items>> = repo.getQuery()
var secondObservale: Flowable<List<Items>> = firstObservable.
.flatMapIterable{list -> list}
.map{ item ->
      cumulativeSum += it.qty
      it.totalQty = cumulativeSum
 }
.toList()
```

If anyone can help me with above query, why  secondObservable is not an Flowable list of items? I am getting it as Single List of units.
Or this is not right way to transform.

Please help me, how can i achieve expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `flatMap` series api, it'll flatten your data and you may lose your initial list.

```
firstObservable.flatMapIterable{list -> list} // This will be converted to Flowable<Items>
```

Also, `map()` operator can convert your object to other one. If you just want to stay your `Items` object and only want to change internal variable, use 'doOnXXX()' operators.

```
var secondObservale: Flowable<List<Items>> = firstObservable
    .doOnNext {
        it.fold(0.0) { acc, items ->
            items.totalQty = acc + items.qty
            items.totalQty
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if there's anything wrong with me.

**Update**

I think RxJava's core functionality is *concurrency*. I'm not sure this scenario is what you want, but if you want to run each tasks concurrently, try below code.

```
var secondObservale: Flowable<List<Items>> = firstObservable
    .parallel(4) // max concurrency: 4
    .runOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .doOnNext {
        it.fold(0.0) { acc, items ->
            items.totalQty = acc + items.qty
            items.totalQty
        }
    }
    .sequential()
```

Comment: Thanks @Minseong , This works. I had confusion about doOnNext and onNext. and it seems this is a intermediate step. so this change will happen on i.o thread(subscriober) itself.

Comment: @AnshulKabra, I'm glad that this answer is what you want. Please check updated code if you want to run your code concurrently.